# Conditioning on strings with special characters

Tags: frameworks, conditional-statements, robotframework

I've run into an unusual situation when I have an apostrophe in my string and need to do a "run keyword if" conditional. Below is my code:

```
*** Variables ***
${myVar} =  Joe's test

*** Test Cases ***
Testing a true IF statement
    Run Keyword If  '${myVar}' == 'Joe's test'  Keyword 1

*** Keywords ***
Keyword 1
    Log to Console  VALUE: ${myVar}
```

I get the following error:

```
Evaluating expression 'Joe's test == 'Joe's test'' failed: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1).
```

I tried using a switch like \' to handle the apostrophe in the string but still no luck. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes:

```
run keyword if  "${myVar}" == "Joe's test"  keyword 1
```

If there's a possibility that `${myVar}` contains either a single quote or a double quote, you can use triple quotes:

```
run keyword if  '''${myVar}''' == "Joe's test"  keyword 1
```